# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException

Tags: c#, sharepoint, client

I have no idea on this. Before of this I'm able to show my Title in the messagebox, but I don't know what I've done and the second day, it shows me the error "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: 'Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) did not get a response from the Login server.'"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KBBR.png)

Anyone know what cause this problem?

I had tried many ways but it still come out the same problem.

First I create a class library.

```
namespace CredentialsFactory
{
    public enum SharePointAuthentication
    {
        SharePointOnline,
        SharePointActiveDirectory
    }
    public class SharePointCredentials101
    {
        
        public static ICredentials CreateCredential(string UserName, string Password,
            SharePointAuthentication authenticationType)
        {
            ICredentials result = null;
            switch (authenticationType)
            {
                case SharePointAuthentication.SharePointActiveDirectory:
                    result = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                    break;

                    case SharePointAuthentication.SharePointOnline:
                    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
                    foreach(char ch in Password.ToCharArray())
                    {
                        securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
                    }
                    result = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName,securePassword);
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Then I create a windows form application .NET Framework.

```
namespace TestFactoryMethod
{
    public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/"))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = CredentialsFactory.SharePointCredentials101.CreateCredential("xxxx.onmicrosoft.com", "xxxx", CredentialsFactory.SharePointAuthentication.SharePointOnline);
                Web myWeb = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(myWeb);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(myWeb.Title);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? My sharepoint code was working then now suddenly I get this error.